# Windows Phone Allignment of a repeating image control

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I am developing an application and I have an image control that displays however many images are stored in the database. So I have got the images to display. However the images are displaying below the previous one and not next to the previous one. [image] 
(ignore the names next to the picture I have taken them out now).

So my question is what method can I use to get them aligned, I'm not sure what I need to search for in Google, everything I can think of doesnt bring back anything close to what I am looking for. The XAML code is below:

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <!--Pivot Control-->
    <phone:Pivot Title="Share This!">
        <!--Pivot item one-->
        <phone:PivotItem Header="All Photos">
            <Grid>
                <ListBox Height="559" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,20,0,0" x:Name="lst_viewPhotos" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="444" FontSize="30" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="lst_viewPhotos_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,0" >
                                <Image Source="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Width="100"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </Grid>
        </phone:PivotItem>
    </phone:Pivot>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get them displaying alongside each other by setting the `ItemsPanel`

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

However I would recommend a GridView for this so that you can use a `Wrapgrid` which will reach the end of a Row or Column and wrap to a new Row or Column.
Something like this

```
<GridView>
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" />
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </GridView.ItemsPanel>
 </GridView>
```

Comment: IS there a way I can set the width, so when there are to many photos to fit on the UI next to the previous it sits under them? I tried setting the width properties and that didn't seem to work, and the can scroll property to false, but that didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried the `GridView` ? if you use set the width of the image to say 100px and use a `WrapGrid` it will wrap the image to a new row when there isn't any more space in the row.

Comment: I think I am just being dumb about this, but I don't have the option for GridView in the XAML code?

Comment: that's weird maybe it only came out for Phone 8.1 and not phone 8 Silverlight. Are you using Visual Studio 2012? Phone 8.1 is on over 90% of handsets so might be worth moving to VS 2013 if youre using free express version

Comment: I am on VS 2013 for 8.1, I am using the universities computers so its all the latest software, and all the updates on the software are up to date. When I add it, it says the namespace doesn't exist in the schema?